# Trying to echo condition by given input but results are three times I want single result condition by given input

Tags: php, html

**hi here is the code please answer my question. I'm trying to echo condition by given input but results are three times I want single result condition by given input **

```
<?php
$arrayName = array('bravo', 'alpha', 'jhony');

foreach ($arrayName as $key) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['num1']) && $_REQUEST['num1'] == $key) {
        echo "yes". $_REQUEST['num1']. "Available";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry!".$_REQUEST['num1']." is not available";
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="num1">
<button type="submit">submit</button></form>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. The way your code is written will give you one `echo` for `bravo`, one for `alpha` and one for `jhony`. Are you only wanting one response for if ANY of the three are available?

Comment: yes if  input is equal to given array, it echo three times. i want only single echo result  for given input...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loop through your white list, use `in_array`:

```
$arrayName = array('bravo','alpha','jhony' );


if(isset($_REQUEST['num1']) && in_array($_REQUEST['num1'], $key)){
 echo "yes". $_REQUEST['num1']. "Available";
}
else{
    echo "Sorry!".$_REQUEST['num1']." is not available";
}
```